# Unable to Perform SOQL Query Involving Lookup Field

Tags: soql, query, lookup

I have a custom object (Registration__c) that has a lookup field (Approver__c) to the standard User object.

I'm trying to construct an SOQL query that will return the user's ID.

My assumption is that since it's a child to parent relationship, the query should be:

```
SELECT Id, Approver__r.Id
FROM Registration__c
```

However, running the above query results in "No such relation 'Approver__r' on entity 'Registration__c'."

What am I missing?

**Update**

Query using 'Approver__c' returns "No such column 'Approver__c' on entity 'Registration__c'."

```
SELECT Id, Approver__c
FROM Registration__c
```

Here's a couple of screenshots showing the custom object (Registration__c) and custom field (Approver__c):

[image: Registration__c custom object]
[image]

**Reference**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a typo out there somewhere? Also, you can get the Id with simply doing `Approver__c`, if that is the field name

Comment: Thanks @SebastianKessel! I don't see anything obvious in terms of typos. I added a couple of screenshots that show the object and field.

Using the `Approver__c` returns a similar error message. Thoughts?

Comment: Does your user have access to the field? How are you doing the query? Apex or Dev Console?

Comment: @SebastianKessel That was the answer! The user did not have access to the field. Changing the field accessibility settings fixed the error.

Thank you so much : ) Did you want to submit your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Done, glad to have been able to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the field exists, and it is spelled properly, it is likely a permissions problem with the user running the query.

Also, if you wish to just get the `Id` of the related record, you can just do `Approver__c` instead of `Approver__r.Id` for simplicity.